# Serial Upvoting

Tags: support

I got hit yesterday with "Serial upvoting" yesterday - a whole bunch of my older answers voted up.  Any insights into what this is?  Just some random person deciding to vote up a bunch of stuff?

Comment: Looks like it all started with http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/6506/9366 I guess they thought +10 wasn't enough

Comment: I was going to comment that it's [likely to be reversed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124842/how-to-act-when-youre-being-serial-upvoted), but looking at your history, it already was reversed... Definitely a bummer.

Answer (score 2):

I just did a cursory check but it seems like that was the case. Someone took notice of some of your older posts and up-voted a bit too quickly.

Comment: Yea - kinda weird the way they all flooded in.

Answer (score -3):

All this voting and scoring system is terribly designed, so much is't pretty much pointless to care about it at all.